# Getting Error when using POST Orders on Shopify

Tags: json, post, shopify

I'm trying to post a new order which comes from another marketplace. I have all the correct information, but for some reason the POST is not accepting or recognizing the variant_id Im sending. It always returns an error saying I'm missing name, price, and title. I'm not sure why this comes. Here is the array Im sending:

```
Array
(
    [order] => Array
        (
            [line_items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2147483647
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [price] => 609
                        )

                )

            [customer] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Jurgen
                    [last_name] => Feuchter Garcia
                    [email] => mail@gmail.com
                )

            [note] =>  /// ***** ORDEN MERCADOLIBRE ***** /// ID DE ORDEN ML: order_number
            [financial_status] => pending
            [tags] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Orden MercadoLibre
                )

        )

)
```

And here is the response:

```
Array
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [order] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Line items is invalid
                )

            [line_items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Name can't be blank
                    [1] => Title can't be blank
                )

        )

)
```

I've tried using the value name variant_id instead of id, and it asked me for the same information. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found out what was wrong, the variant_id was wrong. Apparently if the variant_id is wrong, it tells you that name and title is missing, and if you have it right, it mentions that price line is missing. This is what happened to me. Not totally sure if it works like that, but I got it to work using the correct variant_id and adding pricing for the product.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a price like that and mind that the `id` pertains to a variant id and not the product id.

Your variant with id `214748364` should already be priced before hand in the Shopify admin dashboard (backend).

Comment: true the name of the value for the variant id is "variant_id" not just id. As for the price its as I said to Abhishek, it seems now its a must have for the line_item if you are posting the order.

Answer (score 0):

Error 1 is displayed because Price is not part of line_items.

Error 2 is however strange because, Name and Title are not compulsory parts of line_items. For e.g. below [example](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/order#create) would create an order successfully.

```
    POST /admin/orders.json
    {
      "order": {
        "email": "foo@example.com",
        "fulfillment_status": "fulfilled",
        "send_receipt": true,
        "send_fulfillment_receipt": true,
        "line_items": [
          {
            "variant_id": 447654529,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you look at the shopify documentation for order post, line_item does have a price variable. If you are using variant_id, you must add the quantity and the price it has. Apparently they now made price in line_item a must if you are posting a order to shopify.

Answer (score 0):

> [line_items] => Array
> (
> [0] => Name can't be blank
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel) => Title can't be blank
> )

hi @[Laurel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083675/laurel) This error comes from Shopify whenever the passed variant_id not exists on Shopify, It means that the variation is deleted (Either a whole product or a specific variant option) from the store. You can verify that variant exists using [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/product-variant#get-variants-variant-id). I had also faced the same issue with a Few stores, but after passing the updated variant_id, the issue got resolved and an order was created for the correct item.